# Docker mount from host to remote

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I ran a Flask boilerplate app running on Docker  using `docker run -d -p 80:80 p0bailey/docker-flask`
and it works (`192.168.99.100` displayed a page). Next I cloned same app from [github](https://github.com/p0bailey/docker-flask) and try to mount from host directory into container using:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /Users/username/docker-flask/app:/var/www/app p0bailey/docker-flask
```

I went to url `92.168.99.100` and got `502 Bad Gateway`

What am I doing wrong?

Host is a cent os 7

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
721e7cfac4de        p0bailey/docker-flask   "/usr/bin/supervisord"   10 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   stoic_newton
```

Here's the log

```
$ docker logs 721e7cfac4de
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:295: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-07-28 21:14:32,788 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-07-28 21:14:32,788 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2016-07-28 21:14:32,808 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-07-28 21:14:32,808 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-07-28 21:14:32,808 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-07-28 21:14:33,812 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 10
2016-07-28 21:14:33,813 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi' with pid 11
2016-07-28 21:14:33,869 INFO exited: uwsgi (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-07-28 21:14:34,908 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-07-28 21:14:34,909 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi' with pid 16
2016-07-28 21:14:34,915 INFO exited: uwsgi (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-07-28 21:14:36,920 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi' with pid 17
2016-07-28 21:14:36,926 INFO exited: uwsgi (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-07-28 21:14:39,934 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi' with pid 18
2016-07-28 21:14:39,942 INFO exited: uwsgi (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-07-28 21:14:40,943 INFO gave up: uwsgi entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Comment: What is `92.168.99.100`?  Are you certain that your container is listening to port 80 on that system? Are you certain the container is even running? Show us your diagnostic steps and any errors you are seeing.

Comment: @larsks I updated question with output from `docker ps -a` to show its running

Comment: @larsks I added logs to it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this has to do with read-write permission on /app.
Switching SELinux to permissive mode fixed issue.

```
vim /etc/selinux/config

#look for line SELINUX and set to permissive
SELINUX=permissive
```

Comment: although I have no offering for Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

`-v /Users/username/docker-flask/app:/var/www/app` overrides the content of your container with the content of `/Users/username/docker-flask/app`

If you want to mount `/var/www/app`without lost the original container files use

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/www/app p0bailey/docker-flask
```

Then locate the random location of the volume in your host filesystem using

```
docker inspect -f "{{json .Mounts}}" development-phase \
 | jq '.[] | select(.Destination | contains("/var/www/app"))'
```

Comment: but I do want to mount `/Users/username/docker-flask/app` since the plan is to later make changes and deploy.

Comment: You could use `docker cp` or previously copy the content of `/var/www/app`  (in the container) in your `/Users/username/docker-flask/app` (see https://github.com/p0bailey/docker-flask/tree/master/app)